# How can people submit a form but not have access to full list?

Tags: list, infopath, permissions, list-form

We have a form that does all the things that stated in the blog below:

- Form closes and thanks individual for submission
- User gets an email to a link to their application
- Approver gets an email to the actual form

But I  realized recently that the users can, if the wish, go to 'Site Actions' then 'View all site content' and view ALL applications.

Would anyone know how we can set the permissions to restrict this?

Comment: Thanks for responding. We have changed the permissions to only allow individuals to view their own application(Created by..) but now managers are not able to approve their application has their access has been denied. Would you know a way round this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have handled this in a couple diff ways

1 (this will most closely do what you want). Set document approval for that library...may take some modifications and new permissions for certain users.

2.Use the current library to create a library template and then deploy that template to the site under a new name. Then create a workflow that will copy anything newly submitted to the other library and then delete the orginal from the first. When they finish even if they pick apart the link to snoop they will see nothing.

I have used both methods and they work fairly well.

Answer (score 0):

If you used a list instead of a library, there's just an option to restrict users to only their own items. But that option doesn't exist in a library.

If you can't rework the solution and you're stuck with a library, you can use a SharePoint designer based 2010 workflow to modify the permissions of any new list items.

Comment: Note though that this will cause performance issues later if this is a library that will have lots of items. Item level permissions en mass can degrade performance.